# Dzetsaka plugin of QGIS can't load SVM

Tags: qgis, linux, scikit-learn

I try to install dzetsaka plugin of QGIS. When in MX Linux 21.3, it is ok when I run SVM in dzetsaka plugin.

After I upgrade to MX Linux 23, SVM can't load. There is a message : Scikit-learn library is missing on your computer. MX Linux 23 uses QGIS 3.22.16-Białowieża.

Eventhough I had successfully installed scikit-learn by conda. I also had installed scikit-learn by python3 like in https://github.com/nkarasiak/dzetsaka#installation-of-scikit-learn. The syntax is python3 -m pip install scikit-learn -U --user. Successfull installed. But still can't load SVM. And there is that message.

So, any suggestion?

Comment: ok it is work after I remove pip version as your suggestion. SVM can run well. I think you should answer not in comment. But, anyway thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your distribution package. You may need to remove the pip version.

```
sudo apt install python3-sklearn
```

Comment: thank you. it is work